# How to install Snapper on Ubuntu 16.04 Server using BTRFS as file system

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-16.04, btrfs

I am having some difficulty installing Snapper(http://snapper.io/) on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

When I follow instructions from [Snapper for Ubuntu 16.04](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=filesystems:snapper&package=snapper), I am getting the below error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libsnapper
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
Need to get 197 kB of archives.
After this operation, 674 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1
```

(download.opensuse.org/repositories/filesystems:/snapper/xUbuntu_16.04  libsnapper 0.5.1 Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
E: Failed to fetch)

(download.opensuse.org/repositories/filesystems:/snapper/xUbuntu_16.04/./amd64/libsnapper_0.5.1_amd64.deb  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl)

This seems to work fine for Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. Can I make it work for server???

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the https to http in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapper.list and now it works

This is a work around as opensuse org does not support https i guess.

[https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/357](http://%20it%20is%20general%20issue%20with%20software%20opensuse%20org)